# Laravel Kernel Task Schedule not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I'm trying to use Laravel Task Schedule. So I create `crontab -e` which is like blow.

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/laravel && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

After this I bind my commands to Laravel's App/Kernel which is like below:

```
protected $commands = [
        //
        Commands\mitsui::class,
        Commands\sumitomo::class,
        Commands\nomura::class,

    ];
```

And schedule:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('bot:mitsui')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('bot:sumitomo')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('bot:nomura')->everyMinute();
    }
```

Actually it's weekly but I'm trying to checking is it working or not. That's why make it `everyMinute` But actually it's not working. commands are not running. Do I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/laravel && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
* * * * *  php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```